# Add suffix with imaskjs to html input

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a masked input using [imaskjs][1] by adding a currency symbol (€) at the end.

There is an example for a prefix ($) which works as expected, but assuming this is because it is at the beginning. The library detects something is missing and auto corrects it. In my case, it is still waiting for manual input to complete the first pattern (there could be more numbers for the number pattern)

It works for example if you enter two zeros, or anything that overflows 10 000 (set as a maximum).

I have setup a jsfiddle with the code.
https://jsfiddle.net/7phbaemz/4/

```
var element = document.getElementById('input');
var maskOptions = {
  mask: 'num €',
  blocks: {
    num: {
      mask: Number,  // enable number mask

      scale: 2,
      signed: false, 
      thousandsSeparator: ' ', 
      padFractionalZeros: true,
      normalizeZeros: true,
      radix: ',',
      mapToRadix: ['.'],

      // additional number interval options (e.g.)
      min: 0,
      max: 10000,
    }
  }
}
var mask = IMask(element, maskOptions);
```

How can I automatically format on focus lost?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `element.addEventListener('blur', doSomething)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out at the end.
Lazy evaluation should be disabled:

```js
var maskOptions = {
  lazy: false, // <-- HERE
  mask: 'num €',
  blocks: {
    num: {
      mask: Number
```

It will always check and fix the entire expression on change.